# Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException android

Tags: android, realm

I am getting following exception while user is upgrading from 1 to 3 db schema

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SplashActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Realm on disk need to migrate from v1 to v3
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
 Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Realm on disk need to migrate from v1 to v3
   at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidateFromCache(Realm.java:389)
   at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:364)
   at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:346)
   at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
   at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:273)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)**
```

Realm configuration is as follows:

```
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(AppConstants.DB_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(schemaVersion)
            .build();
    try {
        Realm.migrateRealm(realmConfiguration, new DBMigration()));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // If the Realm file doesn't exist, just ignore.
    }
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

I have specified DB migrations in code in which i have mentioned all DB changes.

I am using realm version 3.3.0

Can you please help in resolving this issue
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just changing the indention

Comment: commented on original issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5062